# Sencha touch map center

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I've created a new sencha app with the sencha-cmd. I'm a bit new to this. So i've tried to create a map:

```
{
            title: 'Map',
            iconCls: 'locate',
            layout: 'card',
            useCurrentLocation: false,
            fullscreen: false,
            id: 'locationmap',
            mapOptions: {
                zoom: 12,
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.381592, -122.135672),
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: 
                {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Getting Started'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'map'
                }
            ]
        }
```

I've included the necessary google maps api files, and also required `Ext.Map`

However the map isn't centering on 37.381592, -122.135672, its centering elsewhere. How can I fix this?

Additionally, how can I access the maps object? So I can call stuff like `.getCenter()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the centering, but you could do it after the fact with:

```
theView.setMapCenter({latitude: 37.381592, longitude: -122.135672});
```

As for getting the element, you can simply call:

```
theView.getMap();
```

This is all coming from the [Sencha Touch 2 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Map), FYI. I'm interested to see how it works out, I'll be implementing a map in my new app soon.

EDIT:
Looking at it more closely, shouldn't your `mapOptions` parameter be on the `xtype: 'map'` item?

```
...
{
  xtype: 'map',
  useCurrentLocation: false,
  mapOptions: {
    zoom: 12,
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.381592, -122.135672),
    navigationControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: 
    {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
    }
  }
}
...
```